# TypeError? pairing lists?

Tags: python

cant get it to calculate distance? (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str') suggestion to get python to recognize which name goes with which number? that way i can get it to print the correct name with the winning times? (str?)

```
def main():
    print "~*~*~*~*~*~ Timbuktu Archery Contest ~*~*~*~*~*~"
    archerList = [] #list
    timeList = [] #list2
    distanceList = [] #list3
    name = raw_input ("Enter contestants first name: ")
    s = str(name)
    archerList.append(name)
    while name:
        time = raw_input ("Enter time (in milliseconds) for %s: " % s)
        timeList.append(time)
        name = raw_input ("Enter contestants first name: ")
        s = str(name)
        archerList.append(name)
    else:
        print "Slowest archer was " , min(timeList)
        print "Fastest archer was " , max(timeList)
    for time in timeList:
        distance = ((230/time)*681.1)
        distanceList.append(distance)
```

Comment: everything you get from `raw_input` is a string. You have to convert it to an appropriate type in your code.

Comment: After running your code, it seems like there may be an infinite loop in your while loop. It may be the platform I'm using (code.hs).

Answer (score 1):

firstly don''t use `time` as a variable, it is a python module

secondly

`time = raw_input ("Enter time (in milliseconds) for %s: " % s)` here `time` is a string

you should convert it to `int` like `timeList.append(int(time))` and then use it for

`distance = ((230/time)*681.1)`

also if you don't convert `min/max` will not give desired output

Comment: suggestion to get python to recognize which name goes with which number? that way i can get it to print the correct name with the winning times? (str?)?

Comment: you would be better of creating a dictionary, with name as the key and time as the value, that way retrieving will be much easier

Answer (score 1):

```
time = raw_input ("Enter time (in milliseconds) for %s: " % s)
```

should be:

```
time = int( raw_input ("Enter time (in milliseconds) for %s: " % s) )
```

or even better:

```
repeat = True
while repeat:
    try:
        time = int(raw_input ("Enter time (in milliseconds) for %s: " % s))
        repeat = False
    except ValueError:
        print "Invalid time."
```

Answer (score 0):

As others already gave you answers "to the point", here rather some additional sinformation.

You have to convert time to `int` or rather `float` first before calculating. Python is strongly typed language. There is no variable type declaration, but nevertheless, every variable has a type.

You should also maybe write `distance = ((230./time)*681.1)` (note the "." behind 230), so that you divide a float by some number. Float division is different from integer division.

Comment: To be precise, there are no variables in Python, only references to typed objects.

Comment: Interesting. This is a really strong position, but makes some particularities easier to understand.